How to get SharePoint site URL or site information from given username in SharePoint 2019
How to get SharePoint site URL or site information from given username in SharePoint 2019
here i have Root Site Collection and it has many Sites & Sub Sites and each site has Unique Permissions.
Here how to achieve my requirement: in Home page of root site collection i want to create a page and i want to add check permission functionally and it retrieve Site information in which that user has permissions
